# Troubles with wifi direct (p2p) refresh

Tags: android, wifi-direct, wifip2p

I've got some troubles with detecting other devices using Wifi Direct on Sony Xperia M in an android application which I develop. This issue appears when device woke up from sleep mode after few hours. It doesn't detect other devices after this.

I use WifiP2pManager discoverPeers() to refresh peer list, but unfortunately it doesn't work on this Sony device.

May be somebody know how to deal with it...